# Can apache proxy/load balancer redirect requests to other available balancer member when it gets timeout from a hanging server?

Tags: load-balancing, apache-2.4

I am using apache2.4.6 and tomcat8 to implement a load balance solution.

I'd like to know whether apache balancer will redirect requests to another balancer member if it gets timeout error from one server.

For example, apache sends one request to tomcat1 but tomcat1 cannot respond within 10 seconds, will apache resend this request to tomcat2?

Below is my configuration for apache proxy balancer.

```
<Proxy balancer://myCluster timeout=10 failontimeout=on>
    BalancerMember http://server1:8080 route=tomcat1 loadfactor=1 timeout=10 retry=30
    BalancerMember http://server2:8080 route=tomcat2 loadfactor=1 timeout=10 retry=30

    ProxySet lbmethod=byrequests
   # ProxySet stickysession=JSESSIONID

    Order Deny,Allow
    Deny from none
    Allow from all
 </Proxy>
```

Answer (score 0):

I belive you can achieve this feature by using second tomcat server as a hot standby. This is supported with mod_proxy in apache

You can try following configuration & test it.

```
<Proxy balancer://myCluster timeout=10 failontimeout=on>
    BalancerMember http://server1:8080 route=tomcat1 loadfactor=1 timeout=10 retry=30
    BalancerMember http://server2:8080 route=tomcat2 loadfactor=1 timeout=10 retry=30 status=+H

    ProxySet lbmethod=byrequests
   # ProxySet stickysession=JSESSIONID

    Order Deny,Allow
    Deny from none
    Allow from all
 </Proxy>
```

Comment: With this configuration, does that mean all the requests will be distribute to tomcat1 if tomcat1 is available?

Once tomcat1 is down, then requests will be distribute to tomcat2?

Comment: Yes. All requests will go to Tomcat1 until it is available. If it goes down, requests will be routed to tomcat2 instance.